# Running bower gives me module.js:340 throw err

Tags: error-handling, bower

When I try to run `bower` in the `cmd` I get:

```
C:\wamp\www\budgeteer\v4\static>bower

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mout'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Imray\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower:7:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

What is this error and why am I getting it? I wish the error message would explain more

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the "bower" package from your node_modules folder.

```
C:\wamp\www\budgeteer\v4\static> npm uninstall bower
```